# TFS 2012 Licensing via Action Pack

Tags: licensing, actionpack

I currently have an Microsoft Action Pack but I don't see a license for TFS included in it. What would be the best way of getting TFS 2012 Server installed and access for 6 devs and 2 Web access users.

I've read the Microsoft Licensing White Papers and they are next to useless. Does anyone have any concrete examples of the best way to get this done? Do I just purchase a Server License and 6/8 CALS, it seems I should be able to reuse some part of the Action Pack to reduce this cost, no?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try contacting the Microsoft partners support (they have live chat):

https://mspartner.microsoft.com/en/uk/Pages/Support/partner-network-support.aspx?Page=CustomerServiceControlJsonP